# Is there a Dedekind-Frobenius group determinant for infinite groups?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, rt.representation-theory, reference-request, soft-question

If $G$ is a finite group and $\lbrace x_{g} \rbrace_{g\in G}$ are commuting formal variables, then one can form a matrix whose $(g,h)$ entry is $x_{gh^{-1}}$. The determinant of this matrix is a polynomial with integer coefficients and is called the *group determinant*. Considering the factorization of this determinant led Frobenius to discover seminal results in the representation theory of finite groups. [Later on](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2159470), it was shown that a group can be recovered from its group determinant.

Many people have asked me the following question over the years, and I haven't a good answer for it. One might think about looking at something like a generalized determinant over a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables indexed by the group.

> **Question:** In the literature, does there exist a
>   *more or less direct* attempt to generalize the Dedekind-Frobenius
>   group determinant to the setting of
>   infinite groups?

Moreover, if such a thing exists, can it determine the group from which it is constructed?

Comment: Jon, does the Fuglede-Kadison determinant have some of the properties you're after?

Comment: @Yemon: I hope so, actually. (This is why I've included the operator algebras tag.) Perhaps the composition of the thing I'm looking for, which might take values in a commutative operator algebra, with some state should give the KF determinant. I can't see clearly what should happen.

Comment: I meant to type "pure state" in the comment above...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a thing is defined in Steve Humphries' very interesting paper:

Humphries, Stephen P.(1-BYU)
Cogrowth of groups and the Dedekind-Frobenius group determinant. 
Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 121 (1997), no. 2, 193–217

I am not sure it is as general as you might like, but...

Comment: Thanks Igor! I'm happy that there is a positive answer to this question, even a less than fully general one. I'll have to interlibrary loan this ASAP.